# How do I change Nautilus 3.6 symbolic icons?

Tags: nautilus, themes, icons

I have the new Nautilus 3.6 installed and the new symbolic icons for Home and Trash don't fit with the rest of my icon theme. How would I be able to change these icons? Is there a certain name I must give to the files I want in my theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they **need** to have a very specific name and a very specific **color** else they won't work. You can check them in `/usr/share/gnome/scalable`. Inside this folder are **all** the Gnome symbolic icons.